# Upgrading to 12.04

Tags: upgrade

I am not confident upgrading to 12.04 online. I have downloaded the 12.04 iso image and will burn the CD. May I use the CD to upgrade to 12.04, saving all my current settings and files?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Just go ahead and pop the CD in and select `Install Ubuntu` and when it detects what OSs are already on the drive it will ask if you wish to upgrade to 12.04.

Before any upgrade I recommend you back up your data!! The source links has pictures if you wish to reference those.

Sources: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-12-04-from-11-10-using-ubuntu-cd-dvd/?ModPagespeed=noscript